# Stop traefik ingress from replying to IP requests

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, traefik

We have a GCP GKE setup with traefik as our ingress.

The problem is that when we hit (http GET) the IP of our LB, traefik responds with the `TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT` (Self signed root certificate).

Can we configure traefik so that it doesn't respond at all, or at least it responds without an invalid certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strict SNI checking solves this partially by dropping the connection in the case of invalid certificate: https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/entrypoints/#strict-sni-checking

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for some guide that configures traefik and it response as your needs. Following these examples, you should be able to configure it without using a cert, especially for port 80.

Some configuration examples of Traefik[https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/examples/]